# Positioning pollution due to several call-outs in beamer

Tags: beamer, callout

In my beamer slide I like to use " \vfill " between each items of an itemize environment (and also at the beginning and end of the slide) so that the slide is fully filled, with blank spaces distributed uniformly.

However this seems to be destroyed when I use some call-outs.

Here's an example. Commenting the call-outs gives the slide that I would like to have (which should not change even when a call-out appears). I don't know if I am clear enough but I would be glad to precise something if needed.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{lipsum,tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns}
\usetikzlibrary {shapes.callouts,positioning}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
  \frametitle{The title}
  \begin{itemize}
  \item Something: {\footnotesize \tikz[baseline=(a.base),remember picture] \node[above] (a) {[a],}; \hspace{-2mm}\tikz[baseline=(b.base),remember picture] \node[above] (b) {[b],}; \hspace{-2mm}\tikz[baseline=(c.base),remember picture] \node[above] (c) {[c]};} 
  \begin{itemize}
    \vfill
\item \lipsum[1][1]
\end{itemize}
  \vfill
\onslide<5->{\item Something else: {\footnotesize \tikz[baseline=(d.base),remember picture] \node[above] (d) {[d]};}
  \begin{itemize}
    \vfill
\item Again again again
  \vfill
\item And again
\end{itemize}}
  \vfill
\onslide<7-9>{\item Almost: {\footnotesize \tikz[baseline=(e.base),remember picture] \node (e) {[e],}; \hspace{-3mm} \tikz[baseline=(f.base),remember picture] \node (f) {[f],}; \hspace{-3mm} \tikz[baseline=(g.base),remember picture] \node[above] (g) {[g],}; \hspace{-3mm} \tikz[baseline=(h.base),remember picture] \node[above] (h) {[H]};}
    \begin{itemize}
      \vfill
    \item over
      \vfill
\item  the end
\end{itemize}}
\vfill
\end{itemize}
\vfill

% Call-outs to be commented, below:

\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
    \draw<2> (a.south) node[align=center,rectangle callout,fill=red!50,opacity=1, callout absolute pointer={(a.south)}] at (3,3.5) {\small This is the thing};
  \end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
    \draw<3> (b.south) node[align=center,rectangle callout,fill=red!50,opacity=1, callout absolute pointer={(b.south)}, below right= 1.5cm and 2pt of b.east]  {\small Another thing here and there and everywhere};
  \end{tikzpicture}


       \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
     \path<4> (c.south) ++(0,0) node[text width=2cm, align=center,rectangle callout,fill=red!50,opacity=1, callout absolute pointer={(c.east)}, right= 1cm of c.east]  {\small Still here};
   \end{tikzpicture}


       \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
         \draw<6> (d.east) node[text width=4cm, align=center,rectangle callout,fill=red!50,opacity=1, callout absolute pointer={(d.east)}, right= 1cm of d.east]  {\small Again !!};
          \end{tikzpicture}

\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem are all the empty lines between your tikz pictures and the unprotected line endings. Once you avoid them by commenting them out, you get the same layout:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{lipsum,tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns}
\usetikzlibrary {shapes.callouts,positioning}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
  \frametitle{The title}
  \begin{itemize}
  \item Something: {\footnotesize \tikz[baseline=(a.base),remember picture] \node[above] (a) {[a],}; \hspace{-2mm}\tikz[baseline=(b.base),remember picture] \node[above] (b) {[b],}; \hspace{-2mm}\tikz[baseline=(c.base),remember picture] \node[above] (c) {[c]};} 
  \begin{itemize}
    \vfill
\item \lipsum[1][1]
\end{itemize}
  \vfill
\onslide<5->{\item Something else: {\footnotesize \tikz[baseline=(d.base),remember picture] \node[above] (d) {[d]};}
  \begin{itemize}
    \vfill
\item Again again again
  \vfill
\item And again
\end{itemize}}
  \vfill
\onslide<7-9>{\item Almost: {\footnotesize \tikz[baseline=(e.base),remember picture] \node (e) {[e],}; \hspace{-3mm} \tikz[baseline=(f.base),remember picture] \node (f) {[f],}; \hspace{-3mm} \tikz[baseline=(g.base),remember picture] \node[above] (g) {[g],}; \hspace{-3mm} \tikz[baseline=(h.base),remember picture] \node[above] (h) {[H]};}
    \begin{itemize}
      \vfill
    \item over
      \vfill
\item  the end
\end{itemize}}
\vfill
\end{itemize}
\vfill
%
% Call-outs to be commented, below:
%
\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
    \draw<2> (a.south) node[align=center,rectangle callout,fill=red!50,opacity=1, callout absolute pointer={(a.south)}] at (3,3.5) {\small This is the thing};
  \end{tikzpicture}%
%
\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
    \draw<3> (b.south) node[align=center,rectangle callout,fill=red!50,opacity=1, callout absolute pointer={(b.south)}, below right= 1.5cm and 2pt of b.east]  {\small Another thing here and there and everywhere};
  \end{tikzpicture}%
%
%
       \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
     \path<4> (c.south) ++(0,0) node[text width=2cm, align=center,rectangle callout,fill=red!50,opacity=1, callout absolute pointer={(c.east)}, right= 1cm of c.east]  {\small Still here};
   \end{tikzpicture}%
%
%
       \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
         \draw<6> (d.east) node[text width=4cm, align=center,rectangle callout,fill=red!50,opacity=1, callout absolute pointer={(d.east)}, right= 1cm of d.east]  {\small Again !!};
          \end{tikzpicture}%
%
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Man that was simple but I think I never would have noticed it ... Thanks !

Comment: @xounamoun You're welcome!

Comment: @xounamoun You can probably simplify your code a bit by placing them all in a single tikzpicture ...

Comment: and you're not seeing the true version of the code ... I should introduce a single command to produce these callouts but I am bit in a rush ... Thanks again !

Comment: @xounamoun Ah, one of those documents :) Good luck!